# html rangeslider javascript not working and no error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

In my railsapplication I want to add an output for the rangesliders of the nested form.
I found this CodePen: http://codepen.io/thelifemgmt/pen/CeLqA

my stuff:
_task_fields.html.haml

```
.nested-fields
  .range-slider
    = f.input :ur, as: :range, input_html: { min: '1', max: '4', class: 'range-slider__range'}
  %span.range-slider__value 0
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require cocoon
//= require_tree .

var rangeSlider = function(){
  var slider = $('.range-slider'),
      range = $('.range-slider__range'),
      value = $('.range-slider__value');

  slider.each(function(){

    value.each(function(){
      var value = $(this).prev().attr('value');
      $(this).html(value);
    });

    range.on('input', function(){
      $(this).next(value).html(this.value);
    });
  });
};

rangeSlider();
```

Its not working and I dont get an error.

Comment: Where did the title of your question come from if you're not getting an error? Assuming the title is the error you got, where in your code are you trying to use the `innerHTML` method? It doesn't seem as though you've included all relevant code.

Comment: @MarsAtomic sry for this confusion, my code is complete, just chose the wrong title, long story. How ever I fixed it